# Just Published 1st App. It works fine on my Nexus 4 Running 4.2, but friend says it crashes on shake on her Electrify M Motorola running 4.1

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I have a question and would really appreciate any help.

My friend says the app crashes onshake. My first app is a simple magic 8 ball app, that gives a random answer when the user shakes it. She says after she opens the app, and shakes the app instead of receiving a random answer like I do on my nexus 4, the app simply shutsdown and takes her back to her home screen.

Here's the code that I think may be causing it. I added the "Finish(); to shut down the activity after a user hits the homescreen, so it would clear out the randomly generated answer instead of storing it for days.

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(mShakeDetector);
    finish();
```

Comment: Is the app already in the market? If so check the developer console for the crash reports you get there. That should give you a good starting point...

Comment: Hello Warren, I did look, but it says 0 crashes? Is it possible there'sa  bug that won't show in the crash reports?

Answer (score 1):

Try to get a crash log, including the complete stack trace. The easiest way to do that is asking your friend to send a crash report when Android asks him. Otherwise plug his phone into your computer, crash the app and copy the output of `adb logcat`. The crash log should help you pinpoint which line in your code causes the crash.

If you are really sure the problem is in the `onPause` method, check how you initialize `mSensorManager`. Is there a way it might be `null` (not initialized) on your friend's phone? (As that would cause a `NullPointerException`.)